# Weyl's law for eigenvalues

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, laplacian

I am calculating the eigenvalues of Laplacian on sphere. The Laplace's problem(with the Dirichlet's boundary condition)  on sphere is as follows: $$L u + \lambda u = 0$$ where $L$ has the  following meaning.

[image]

Now I am interested in computing the Weyl's law for the sphere. Weyl's law for bounded domain is as follows.

[image]

where $N(\lambda)$ is the eigenvalue counting function, that is, $N(\lambda)$ is the number of eigenvalues less than or equal to $\lambda$ for a given $\lambda$. Now , my question is what is Weyl's for sphere, more precisely, how to verify Weyl's law for the sphere?

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

See theorem 22.1 [here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/%7Ehg94/pdst11/pdst11_sphere.pdf) - there is a complete derivation of the eigenfunctions (and eigenvalues) of the Laplace operator on the sphere.